# How to send back message from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I want to popup success or failure notification of form after form submission.

I have a Partial View as `_Appointment.cshtml` with a form on it.

I have one Main view Index on which i am loading it like this

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Appointments/_Appointment.cshtml", Model);}
```

In Controller i have

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult _Appointment_public(Appointments appointments)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {          
        db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
        db.SaveChanges();
        // return RedirectToAction("Index");
        ViewBag.Success = "Successfull";
        // RedirectToAction("../Home/Index");           
    }

    return Json(new {message = "Test" });
}
```

How do I pass and accept JSON Data to my view?

Comment: how are you doing your form submission?  if an ajax call you can do the message on success.  if a post back you can show something in razor or do a popup in jquery on document.ready

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your partial view you need JavaScript code to make an Ajax call (assuming you are using jQuery with MVC).
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

In your post action in your controller make sure you return Json data, as you are correctly doing. In the Success function in your JavaScript code, get the data and handle it as appropriate. You may want to return "true" or "false" and then do whatever you need to do. This could be from displaying a JavaScript alert to the user, to hiding the form's span/div and display another message instead.

If you need more complex data, you can also return that data from your controller and use jQuery to render that data in another div.